# jasperreport groovy script if..else statement

Tags: groovy, jasper-reports

I try to use expression in a text field, and the language is set to groovy, what I input is a very simple if else statement

```
if ($P{P_TFE_TYPE} == null || $P{P_TFE_TYPE} == ""){
   "abc"
}else{
   "def"
}
```

but this already throw exception as

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling  report expressions class file: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
>
> calculator_RPT0010_1542190583832_137322: 472: unexpected token: if @ line 472, column 22.
>   1 error
>   .
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler.compileUnits(JRGroovyCompiler.java:109)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:203)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:286)
>       at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController.compileJasperDesign(ReportController.java:481)
>       at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController.access$8(ReportController.java:466)
>       at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController$1.run(ReportController.java:369)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
>   Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
>   calculator_RPT0010_1542190583832_137322: 472: unexpected token: if @ line 472, column 22.
>   1 error
>
> at  org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:132)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:360)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:145)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:111)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:237)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:167)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:931)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:593)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler.compileUnits(JRGroovyCompiler.java:102)
>       ... 6 more

what is the problem?

I see a red underline under the opening {, and the tool tip is

> missing EOF at '{'

if I use expression like

```
($P{P_TFE_TYPE} == null || $P{P_TFE_TYPE} == "")?"abc":"def"
```

it can compile, everything run as expected.

I know I can use ?: operator but don't want to as my if..else if condition is quite lengthy and complicated in reality, and feel hard to see if use tenary operator ?:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use if in expression.

in other words you can do this:

```
x = y==1 ? 'a' 'b'
```

but you can't do this:

```
x = if( y==1 ){ 'a' }else{ 'b' }
```

however you can try to use closure. for example like this:

```
this.with{
    if(x==1){
        return 'a'
    }else{
        return 'b'
    }
    return '0'
}
```

`with` is a method that evaluates closure against the object

Comment: Why cannot use if in expression?  And if inside this.with{, can use nested if then else statement?

Comment: `if` is a statement. and as other statements (`while`, `switch`) you cant use them in evaluation expressions. check java language basics: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html And `this.with` actually calls a groovy closure - like an unnamed function, where you can use any statements and language blocks...

Comment: Did you try this solution at JasperReports template?